# What is the number prepended to the Sublime Text "Goto Anything" search?

Tags: sublimetext, fuzzy-search, string-search

Whenever I use the Goto Anything search in Sublime Text and start typing to search the files in my current project I get a whole bunch of results based on Sublime Text's fuzzy-search algorithm, each prepended with a number.

I assume this is some sort of score for the search "strength" but I just wanted confirm this. What is this number based on?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the numbers are indeed representative of match strength, as you assumed.

I noticed an odd effect when testing your hypothesis, and then proceeded to create the dummy files `CustomCompletions.CustomCompletions` & `CustomCompletions` ( *a file with no extension* ) for further comparison.

---

Here are the results:

[image: Demo]

---

As you can see,

1. `CustomCompletions` has the highest ranking with `1524`
2. `CustomCompletions.py` & `CustomCompletions.todo` share a rank of `1507`
3. `CustomCompletions.CustomCompletions` & `CustomCompletions.sublime-settings` share a rank of `1490`
4. All of the remaining files, which contain additional text in the base name, continue to receive lower rankings.

---

What I found odd was that the 2nd & 3rd groups had different rankings, despite sharing a base file name that exactly matches the query.

I figured that it might be due to the number of characters in the file extension, so I tested that assumption by creating the following files:

```
CustomCompletions.a
CustomCompletions.ab
CustomCompletions.abc
CustomCompletions.abcd
CustomCompletions.abcde
CustomCompletions.abcdef
CustomCompletions.abcdefg
CustomCompletions.abcdefgh
CustomCompletions.abcdefghi
CustomCompletions.abcdefghij

CustomCompletions.1
CustomCompletions.12
CustomCompletions.123
CustomCompletions.1234
CustomCompletions.12345
CustomCompletions.123456
CustomCompletions.1234567
CustomCompletions.12345678
CustomCompletions.123456789
CustomCompletions.1234567890
```

But it turns out they all ranked at `1507`, the same ranking as the 2nd group.

Because of that outcome, I am still unsure what criteria affects the ranking of files which share a base name that is an exact match for the `Goto Anything` query, but have differing file extensions.